# How to Expand and collapse WinRTXamlToolkit Treeview programmatically?

Tags: uwp, treeview, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Can someone guide me how programmatically expand and collapse the tree and subtrees?
I currently do not use a property called IsExpand.

My view

```
<controls:TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeviewDataTemplate}"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" Style="{StaticResource TouchTreeViewStyle}"
                                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

Data binding on TreeViewpageViewModel:

```
 private void BuildTree()
        {
            var tree = BuildChildrenTree(_fullAgendaItems.Where(a => a.PreviousId == null).ToList());
            TreeItems = tree;
        }
```

and

```
private ObservableCollection<AgendaItem> BuildChildrenTree(List<AgendaItem> agendaItems)
    {
        var tree = new ObservableCollection<AgendaItem>();
        const string functionName = "BuildChildrenTree";
        try
        {
            //Logs.Write.Entry(ClassName + functionName);
            foreach (var item in agendaItems)
            {
                item.Children =
                    BuildChildrenTree(
                        FullAgendaItems.Where(a => a.PreviousId == item.Id && item.HeadorPaper == 0).ToList());// 

                #region Change bg color of the currently seleted item

                if (_globalSelectedAgendaItem != null && _globalSelectedAgendaItem.Id == item.Id)
                {
                    item.AgendaItemDefaultBg = SelectedColor;
                }

                #endregion

                tree.Add(item);
            }
            //Logs.Write.Success(ClassName + functionName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.Write.Error(Utility.FmtErrData(ClassName + functionName, ex));
        }
        return tree;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For `TreeView` in `WinRTXamlToolkit`, every [`TreeViewItem`](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeViewItem.cs) in the `TreeView` has the `IsExpand` property. You could get the `TreeViewItem` you want to expand or collapse code behind and set `IsExpand` property for it.

To use `ContainerFromItem` method to get the `TreeViewItem` by the items you bind to the `TreeView`, in your code snippet should be `AgendaItem`.

Suppose your `TreeView` is named with `tvDataBound`, the following code snippet will expand the first item.

```
private void BtnExpand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)tvDataBound.ContainerFromItem(tvDataBound.Items[0]);
    if (!item.IsExpanded)
    {
        item.IsExpanded = true;
    } 
}
```

By the way, the official sample provide a [`TreeView`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlTreeView) you could also reference, it is setting `Expand` property with `TreeViewNode`. Also in the insider preview, UWP app provide a [`TreeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) control.

Comment: I need help with  WinRTXamlToolkit Treeview, is this related to  WinRTXamlToolkit?

Comment: @SurenSaluka, the solution I provided firstly is  just for `Treeview` in WInRTXAMLToolkit, you could test. The link above is also one page of WinRTXAMLTookit package. Please check it for details.